# Retrieving whole row from database .Max()

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, max

I take in a text file and use it to fill in a string array (addresses) and from there I'm trying to retrieve 2 columns from a database, the problem is that one address can have many IDs and i'm trying to retrieve the latest assigned one (Max) aswell as a seperate reference number.

```
For Each item In addresses
        Dim reportInfo = (From Reports In DB.ReportDB 
        Where Reports.Address.Contains(item) 
        Select ID = Reports.ID,
        Ref = Reports.Ref).Max(Function(Reports) Reports.Ref)
```

This just returns the ID and sets query = to it, whereas I want the elements in the database correspondent to that ID.

The other issue is that I get a no elements in sequence error which could refer to Ref there isn't always one, but when I checked for null it still gave the error.

Oh and apparently `.LastorDefault` isn't supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
For Each item In addresses
    Dim reportInfo = (From Reports In DB.ReportDB 
    Where Reports.Address.Contains(item) 
    Orderby Reports.Ref
    Select new with{.ID = Reports.ID,
    .Ref = Reports.Ref}).Last()
```

Comment: Would work except i get exception The query operator 'Last' is not supported.

Comment: Did .ToArray() and then reportInfo.Last.ID and seems to work.